# boost::regexp crashes when * is passed as pattern

Tags: boost

When i pass * as  pattern

```
boost::regexp exp("*")
```

program crashes . 
* is acceptable as pattern or not

What is the solution for this ?

Comment: trivia, `*` is semi commonly used as _wildcard_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a valid regex. It's a lone quantifier (so called *Kleene star*) that doesn't apply to a preceding atom.

The program "crashes" because you don't handle the [`bad_exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/bad_expression.html) exception thrown